# How do I reverse a function button

Tags: laptop, keyboard, hp-pavilion, function-keys

My old laptop I could press f1 f2 etc no issue and to use extra features there was a function button to press with f1 for example to do something like volume control

My new laptop works the other way round, if I want to use f2 for example I have to press it with function otherwise it does the volume control etc

How can I switch this round to work like a normal keypad and the function button to work for extras

I have a hp pavilion

Answer (score 1):

This is something that has to be done in the BIOS, which you can access right before your computer starts booting. You should look for a setting called "Action Keys Mode".

For more information and how to access the BIOS, see the [following support page](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02035108&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&jumpid=reg_R1002_USEN).

If F10 does not work for opening the BIOS screen (and the laptop continues booting), try either ESC, or other F-keys.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference,

on newer keyboards (e.g. laptops)

the fn key is *not* the only key that overrides the BIOS setting.

Assuming *action keys* are the default for *function keys*,
some modifier keys will also override the default.

For example:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> will close the main window
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> will close the subwindow/tab
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> will open global help (**special case** - <kbd>F1</kbd> action key usually has the same function)

Essentially, OS keyboard shortcuts will override action keys.