# Is there any way to reverse the function and media keys on a bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, keyboard, bluetooth, media-keys

Is there any way to reverse the function and media keys on a bluetooth keyboard?

I have a Genius Luxepad 9000 - it is meant for iPad but works on Windows also.

I must hold down the fn key to access the f1..f12 keys, otherwise they just do various media functions.

There is no driver specifically for this device available from the manufacturer.

So I'm wondering if there is any 3rd party tool that can do this.

anyone know?

Comment: I found a similar question here: http://superuser.com/questions/696551/how-do-i-reverse-a-function-button but I was wondering if there is something different about my situation, maybe since it is a bluetooth keyboard that I have - I mean it's not the built in keyboard of the notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I would try KeyTweak, which can be found here:

http://www.pcworld.com/product/947513/keytweak.html

I use it on my Lenovo Y50 UHD to change the NumPad "+" and "Enter" keys to VolUp and VolDown.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that before - but I think it can't handle keys without a keycode... this fn key and another key on the keyboard both don't have scancodes.